# Dynamic Background Colour

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if someone can shed some light on how this effect is achieved?

This site shows a constant changing background colour. 
http://bdw.colorado.edu/#/index.php

I want to utilize the same "ever changing" background colour effect on my site.

Here is the link to my example site: 
http://continuous.be/

(I've found the CSS but not sure how it relates? )

```
  /* == Dynamic Colors ==
        .dynamicbgcolor {
         background-color: rgb(0,149,191); } 
         .dynamiccolor {
         color: rgb(0,149,191); }
     */
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have a tinker now and see how it goes...

Comment: Looking at the testpage you've linked to - the file "/js/main.js" cannot be found, I'm guessing your function is in this file?

Comment: Ok, I linked to /js/ instead of /TEST/js/ ... all the files are there now, however i'm getting this pesky warning in Google Chrome "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html." - and the colour bg isn't working yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using CSS alone.  As Vladislav says there is a `spectrum()` function that does the work using javascript and jQuery. Basically:

- Store an array of colours.
- Use Math.Random randomly pick
  one of the stored colours.
- Using [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the backgroundColor property of the required element.
- On completion of the animation, use [jQuery.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to call the above function in XX seconds time.

**Update**

I've had a look at the test you put up.  You're missing the closing `});` at the end of your script file.  Also, you've only defined the function spectrum, you don't call it.  Add `spectrum(false);` at the end of your file, just within the `});` that you've just added.

Try using Firebug for firefox, this pointed out the missing `});` straight away.

Comment: So I think I've got most of the code needed - but something is going wrong... Can anyone see what's happening?

Comment: YES! Thank you Fermin! - It is now working!!! 

Do you know if there is a good debug add on for Chrome? I'll have to re-download Firefox, I switched to chrome a while back.

Comment: I think Chrome comes with Developer tools built in, I've not used them.  I much prefer Firebug!

Answer (score 1):

this is done using JavaScript - the script animates the CSS. Look in http://bdw.colorado.edu/js/main.js for `function spectrum(bool)`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple. They load [js script](http://bdw.colorado.edu/js/main.js) to their page. And there (from line 373) you will find necessary code (together with hardcoded background colors.